# JFreeChart DateTickUnit does not work properly

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am giving user change ability  to filter graph result.For example user can select to show results for 2 day.Then TimeUnitType  is day, timeAmount is 2.But This is not work properly.For this case,  it must be only 2 thick unit.Date related to first day must be shown in related tick unit. Another data related to day 2 must be shown in second thick unit.

For example by default 1 day is selected.It shows a black line under domain axis.

[image: Domain Axis view]

I am selecting 1 month interval .DomainAxis does not show any thick.

```
    private void customizeGraphView(JFreeChart chart, TimeUnitType timeUnit, Integer timeAmount) {
    CombinedRangeXYPlot combinedPlot = (CombinedRangeXYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    /** read 2 subplot*/
    List<XYPlot> subPlots = combinedPlot.getSubplots();
    for (int plotIndex = 0; plotIndex < subPlots.size(); plotIndex++) {
        /** get plot */
        XYPlot plot = subPlots.get(plotIndex);
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
        // plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);
        XYItemRenderer itemRenderer = plot.getRenderer();
        /** if line and shape rendere */
        if (itemRenderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
            StandardXYItemRenderer renderer = (StandardXYItemRenderer) itemRenderer;
            /** show shapes in time series */
            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
            /** fill shapes in time series */
            renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setBaseFillPaint(Color.BLACK);
            // addItemLabels(renderer);
        }
        /** change DateAxis specific vaues */
        DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        /** change Date Axis Time Unit format */
        dateAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
        /** add severity bar */
        if (plotIndex == 0) {
            dateAxis.setAutoRange(true);
            if(getFirstGraphMinRange() != null && getFirstGraphMaxRange() != null)
            {
                dateAxis.setRange(getHistoryGraphMinRange(), getHistoryGraphMaxRange());
                dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(getTickUnitType(timeUnit), timeAmount));
            }
        } else {
            dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()));
            dateAxis.setRange(getSecondGraphMinRange(), getSecondGraphMaxRange());
            dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MINUTE, 5));
        }
    }

}

    /**
 * @param timeUnit
 * @return
 */
private DateTickUnitType getTickUnitType(TimeUnitType timeUnit) {
    DateTickUnitType unitType = null;
    switch (timeUnit) {
    case HOUR:
        unitType = DateTickUnitType.HOUR;
    break;
    case DAY:
        unitType = DateTickUnitType.DAY;
    break;
    case MONTH:
        unitType = DateTickUnitType.MONTH;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
    return unitType;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to find the problem with what you posted as there are other parameters that might affect that behavior.

For example, if you are using a Timeline that excludes some dates, it may explain why you don't see the ticks.
For example, if you use a tickunit of 1 month and use a timeline that excludes sunday, all the month that started on a Sunday will **not** have a tick.
You can try using a timeline that includes all the dates to see if the problem still happens.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, you are trying to set the tickunit to 4 days with a chart that has a date range of a few hours. I am not sure what is the expected behavior of such a seutp. If I replicate those parameters on such a chart, I don't see any ticks on the date axis either. If I setup the tickunit to 10 minutes instead (for example) I can see the ticks again.

I suppose the conclusion is that your tickunit has to be granular enough so that there is at least 1 tick on your chart to make sure it is seen (in other words, the duration between 2 ticks has to be less than the date range).

If you want more control on the domain axis, you might prefer to use a custom NumberAxis instead of a DateAxis (see [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=27425) for example).

Comment: I am not using TimeLine.I am using DateAxis with TimeSeries Collection.

Comment: I have a question.If I set TimeUnit to DAY, All data items in Time series must be new Day() format?So for TimeUnit MONTH,  TimeSeriesDataItem timeDataItem = new TimeSeriesDataItem(new Month(new Date(),
  0.3);

Comment: I don't see anything obvious... Have you checked (printf) the values of the parameters on those 2 lines: `dateAxis.setRange(getHistoryGraphMinRange(), getHistoryGraphMaxRange());` and `dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(getTickUnitType(timeUnit), timeAmount));`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the following `else` to see if it works when you only change `plot(0)` and / or setting the `DateAxis` of plot > 1 to the `DateAxis` of plot(0) ?

Comment: this is result of println.It is correctly set min date: Fri Feb 17 17:36:11 EET 2012max date: Fri Feb 17 18:43:00 EET 2012
DateTickUnitType.DAY
4

Comment: I removed else statment this is not work.I can not understand second statement.Their Domain Axis is different.If I use same, second graph also change.I do not want  to this

Comment: I use `domainAxis.setAutoRange(true)`

Comment: I think that I can not use TimeSeriesCollection if I use NumberAxis,how I will convert Time values to number format to include all my range